# servicestack - caching a service response using redis

Tags: caching, redis, servicestack

I have a servicestack service which when called via the browser (restful) Url ex:`http://localhost:1616/myproducts`, it works fine. 
The service method has RedisCaching enabled. So first time it hits the data repository and caches it for subsequent use.

My problem is when I try calling it from a c# client via Soap12ServiceClient. It returns the below error:

```
Error in line 1 position 183. Expecting element '<target response>' 
from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/<target namespace>'.. 
Encountered 'Element'  with name 'base64Binary', 
namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.
```

Below is my Client code:

```
 var endpointURI = "http://mydevelopmentapi.serverhostingservices.com:1616/"; 
 using (IServiceClient client = new Soap12ServiceClient(endpointURI))
 {
    var request = new ProductRequest { Param1 = "xy23432"};
    client.Send<ProductResponse>(request);
 }
```

It seems that the soapwsdl used is giving the problem, but I appear to have used the defaults as generated by servicestack..

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Update**

I was able over come this error by changing the cache code at the service end:

**Code that returned error at client end:**

```
return RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(this.CacheClient, cacheKey,
       () =>
       new ProductResponse(){CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow, 
                    products = new productRepository().Getproducts(request)
     });
```

**Code that works now:**

```
var result = this.CacheClient.Get<ProductResponse>(cacheKey);
            if (result == null)
            {
                this.CacheClient.Set<ProductResponse>(cacheKey, productResult); 
                result = productResult;
            }
return result;
```

But I am still curious to know why the first method (RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache) returned error at c# client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**But I am still curious to know why the first method (RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache) returned error at c# client?**

From what I can tell, the `ToOptimizedResultUsingCache` is trying to pull a specific format (xml, html, json, etc) out of the cache based on the `RequestContext's ResponseContentType` (see code [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CacheAccess.Providers/CacheClientExtensions.cs#L35) and [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CacheAccess.Providers/CacheClientExtensions.cs#L154)). When using the Soap12ServiceClient the ResponseContentType is text/html (not sure if this is correct/intentional within ServiceStack). So what `ToOptimizedResultUsingCache` is pulling out of the cache is a string of html. The html string is being returned to the Soap12ServiceClient and causing an exception.

By pulling directly out of the cache you are bypassing `ToOptimizedResultUsingCache's` 'format check' and returning something the Soap12ServiceClient can handle.

** If you are using Redis and creating your key with UrnId.Create method you should see a key like urn:ProductResponse:{yourkey}.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response paaschpa.
I revisited the code and I was able to fix it. Since your response gave me the direction,  I have accepted your answer. Below is my fix.

I moved the **return** statement from RequestContext to the response DTO.

**Code which throws error  when used via c# client (code was returning entire requestcontext):**

```
return RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(this.CacheClient, cacheKey,
       () =>
       new ProductResponse(){CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow, 
                    products = new productRepository().Getproducts(request)
     });
```

**Fixed Code (return moved to response DTO):**

```
RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(this.CacheClient, cacheKey,
       () => {
               return new ProductResponse(){CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow, 
               products = new productRepository().Getproducts(request)
              }
     });
```

Comment: Are you returning the cached result somewhere? the return inside your anonymous function is not the return value for the service call.